# regex split on `q` if not a `\q` inside `<>`

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will split on anything between `<` and `>` if it doesn't contain a `q` that isn't a `\q`. Here's what I mean:

```
       split           nope             split
         v              v                 v
test1< test2 > test3 <tesqt4> test5 < tes\qt6>
```

I want to do this without using lookaheads or lookbehinds.

Here's what I have so far but it's still not working [`^<(?:[^\\][^q]*)*>`](http://regexr.com?345jc)

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close; try this

```
<([^>q\\]*(\\[^>])?)*>
```

This will also recognise cases like `<test\\q>` as being invalid, and will reject the malformed `<test\>`. If you want to accept the latter, change the `[^>]` to the wildcard `.`.

It works by allowing anything up to the closing tag, an invalid `q`, or an escaping `\`. Then it checks if the next bit is a valid escape sequence, then "loops", until it finds the closing `>`

Update: as pointed out in the comments, this is a better version

```
<(\\[^>]|[^\\>q])*>
```

It's about twice as fast on Chrome (http://jsperf.com/nested-regex-quantifiers-vs-or) Could be easier to understand too, because it's working at a per-character level.

Comment: +1. Nice. NB to be clear for future readers, this will also match on eg `<anyOtherEscaped\Letter>` (which I think is implied OK by the OP) and not on eg `<OtherEscaped\LetterWithAq>`.

Comment: @Sepster quite right. From the question I think that's what's wanted. Any future readers wanting to allow only specific escaped characters should change the `[^>]` bit to `[theCharactersIWantToAllowHere]` and should probably include `\\ ` since that's fairly typical. Similarly, the `q` on the left can be changed to any collection of characters to *disallow* as plain (non-escaped) text.

Comment: I'd avoid those nested qantifiers:  `/<(\\[^>]|[^>q])*>/g` ?  It's essentially the same regular expression, just a little cleaner (and I think, easier to read).

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan yup, that's faster too. I did a speed check: http://jsperf.com/nested-regex-quantifiers-vs-or

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan @Dave this is awesome, what would I put in if I also wanted to let `>` be escaped? I seems like I just remove `>` from the first group